What are the singular values of a $2 \times 2$ (lower) unit triangular matrix?
Given some arbitrary real parameter $b \in \mathbb R$, suppose we have the matrix
\begin{align*}
    M = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0
    \\ 
    b & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Following up a generic formula found here,
I decompose
\begin{align*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0
    \\ 
    b & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \frac 1 2 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & -b
    \\ 
    b & 2
    \end{pmatrix}
    +
    \frac 1 2 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & b
    \\ 
    b & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
The singular values $w_1$ and $w_2$ are implicitly given by
\begin{align*}
    \frac{ w_1 + w_2 }{2} = \frac 1 2 \sqrt{ 4 + b^2 },
    \quad     \quad 
    \frac{ w_1 - w_2 }{2} = \frac 1 2 |b|.
\end{align*}
Then adding and subtracting these equations leads to
\begin{align*}
    w_1 = \frac 1 2 \sqrt{ 4 + b^2 } + \frac 1 2 |b|
    \\
    w_2 = \frac 1 2 \sqrt{ 4 + b^2 } - \frac 1 2 |b|
\end{align*}
I would like to know

Whether that reasoning is correct. For instance, the referenced formula might break down in the case of a triangular matrix (e.g., in the link above, what happens if $E = 0$ ? ).
Ideally: what is the geometric interpretation of the SVD of $A$?


See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450097/geometrical-interpretations-of-svd

@Ihf I know that the SVD can be seen as rotation - scaling - rotation, but maybe in the above example there is more structure.
